# Problems with viewing subfolders in a domain (.htaccess)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I read this information in another article:

> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
>  
>   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
>
> ... means that if the file with the specified name in the browser
>   doesn't exist, or the directory in the browser doesn't exist then
>   procede to the rewrite rule below

So I tried to apply it to my .htaccess code to remove .php extensions and other URL formats. Code below:

```
#REWRITE LINKS
Options All +Indexes

#REDIRECT ORIGINAL DOMAIN TO WWW
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^noithateti.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.noithateti.com/$1 [R=301,NC]

#REWRITE LINKS
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^product-details/([a-zA-z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)$ product-details.php?title=$1&id=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^products/([a-zA-z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)$ products.php?title=$1&id=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^result.aspx result.php [L]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC]

#RETURN 404 IF THE FILE CONTAINS .php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} "^[^ ]* .*?\.php[? ].*$"
RewriteRule .* - [R=404,L]
```

However, I cannot view a subfolder of the domain. For example: I cannot view www.example.com/subfolder since I think the server got confused between the file and the existing folders. 
While commenting lines of code one by one, I found the problem is in this line:

```
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC]
```

Surprisingly, this was the line of code that I used to remove all the .php extension. 
Combining the quotes I have read and the code, it made a contradiction. I don't know what should I change in order to solve the following problem. Does anybody have any idea? Please let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `RewriteCond` is only applicable to next `RewriteRule`, not to all the `RewriteRule`.

You can have your rules as this:

```
Options All +Indexes
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^noithateti\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

#RETURN 404 IF THE FILE CONTAINS .php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} "^[^ ]* .*?\.php[? ].*$"
RewriteRule ^ - [R=404,L]

#skip below rules for all existing files and directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^product-details/([\w-]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ product-details.php?title=$1&id=$2 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^products/([\w-]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ products.php?title=$1&id=$2 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^result\.aspx$ result.php [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Also note use of `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f` in your last rule to check existence of corresponding `.php` file before adding `.php` extension.

Comment: Thanks, let me take a look. I learnt something from your answer